# How to adhere adhesive to glazed ceramic?

Tags: adhesives, ceramics

I make decorative "flower" plates layering different shapes & sizes to be hung on a wall or attached to a post in the garden, Each weighs approx 4- 5 lbs.

I use either metal heavy duty picture hangars or PVC pipe elbow. I'm having trouble adhering both to the backs of glazed ceramic dishes.  I've tried E6000 clear glue, GE clear silicone for Windows & doors, Fuze It & PL500 landscaping construction adhesive. All cure for 48 hours and fail to stay on.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google "structural epoxy for glass". I use structural epoxies weekly, and it's hard to find something they can't permanently adhere to. I'd give product recommendations, but I don't think it's allowed, and you'll want to find something local anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider sanding the smoothness off of the back of the dish using a coarse sand paper or even a dremel.  That would give your current glues a better chance to adhere.

Also, it appears that the dish in your picture has a rather tall circular base.  You might be able to drill two opposing holes in that circle using a very thin micro drill bit.  Then run a thin wire between the holes to act as a hanger.

Anything you do choose to do should be done to the plate before you add your artwork.  Get the dangerous, potentially dish damaging moves out of the way before you invest your artwork.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, unfortunately I already did the "pretty side" since I need to know how much weight it will have when testing the hangar.  I will try sanding & got a gorilla glue 2 part opoxy that says it fills surfaces as the plate is not flat.  Last resort is wire plate hangar.

Comment: Please edit this into the question, do not put it as an answer. (You can put in an answer but it has to be a real answer.)